# Why is Mikołaj the Polish reflex of Nicholas?

Tags: names, slavic-languages, polish

The Polish name [Mikołaj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikolaj) is held to correspond to the *Nicholas* family of given names, as evidenced by the Russified name of [Mikołaj Kruszewski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miko%C5%82aj_Kruszewski).

As this is an odd sound change, my question is why? My first guess would be interference from Michał and other variants of *Michael*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are absolutely right, the change N > M is due to the influence of `Michael`.

That happened not only in Polish, but also in

- Ukrainian: `Микола, Миколай` (Mykola, Mykolaj)
- Belarusian: `Мікалай` (Mikalaj)
- Czech and Slovak: `Mikuláš`
- Upper Sorbian: `Mikławš`
- Lower Sorbian: `Miklawš`
- Slovenian: `Miklavž`.

UPD: Best wishes on Saint Nicholas' Day, which is celebrated today by most of the Eastern Orthodox!

Comment: What a happy coincidence.

Comment: Is Микита also due to the same influence?